# Strange HTTP 401 response with nginx in combination with WildFly

Tags: nginx, wildfly

I installed a WildFly 26.0.1 together with nginx as a reverse proxy.
Everything seems to work correctly.
Also the deployment of small WebApp war files within WildFlys admin console works.

But there is a problem when deploying large war files.
I have already set `client_max_body_size` to 100M!

The effect is the following:
While deploying the nginx access.log there shows up an endless loop
`POST /management-upload HTTP/1.1" 401 77`

Again and again
On the client side the request hangs.
The WildFly Log shows no start of deployment.

While with small war files it says:
`POST /management-upload HTTP/1.1" 200 68`

btw: When accessing the WildFly directly (not via the nginx proxy) the deployment works
also with large war files

This is my nginx config:
(Replacing my domain with example.com)

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  client_max_body_size 100M;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_read_timeout  90s;
 }

  location /console {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9990/console;
    proxy_read_timeout  90s;
  }

  location /management {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9990/management;
    proxy_read_timeout  90s;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's weird. The nginx documentation says it would return 413 if the maximum size exceeds. What do you get in the network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Thanks.
I got the the 413 before I added „client_max_body_size 100M“
I think the problem might be:
nginx chunks the file while sendfile() and WildFly sees this as
unauthorized access? Therefor the 401.
On WildFly side, I have already activated audit and access log.
No problem is shown.
Of course I tried it with other browsers and cookies removed.
Your tip with network tab I will try.